# Resources for quantum algorithm basics

Tags: quantum-algorithms, experimental-realization, programming, resource-request

I have just started to learn about quantum computing, and I know a little bit about qubits. What is a resource where I can learn a basic quantum algorithm and the concepts behind how it works?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most textbooks and lecture courses start with solving the Deutsch problem using quantum computing.

Parts 1 to 4 of John Watrous's lecture notes will describe the concepts, starting from basics. By the end of lecture 4, you will have learned how a quantum computer can solve the Deutsch problem with fewer operations than a classical computer would need.

All 22 lecture notes can be found [here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ewatrous/QC-notes/).

Answer (score 3):

I suggest a good introductory book, but using lots of linear algebra, and it covers several nice topics. I really, really, love this book:

1) [Quantum Computing Explained](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470096993)

I recommend my advisor's book because it has a very nice view on Grover's algorithm and a good explanation on it.

2) [Quantum Walks and Search Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1461463351)

Answer (score 3):

The best book I could suggest is from Yanofsky and Mannucci [Quantum Computing for Computer Scientists](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521879965). You would find very detailed and very numerical examples rather than abstract theorems which I believe is better in the beginner level.

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer to learn while coding, check out the [Quantum Katas](https://github.com/Microsoft/QuantumKatas). There are katas for teleportation, Deutsch-Jozsa, Grover's, and Simon's algorithms, among others.

Answer (score 1):

I created [this simple video lecture](https://youtu.be/F_Riqjdh2oM) aimed at computer scientists, which explains how basic quantum circuits work mathematically and how you can use them to solve the Deutsch Oracle problem: the simplest problem where a quantum computer outperforms a classical computer in some sense. I tried to make the lecture I would have wanted to watch when originally struggling through introductory textbooks on quantum computing (I used *Quantum Computing for Computer Scientists* by Mannucci & Yanofsky and *Quantum Computer Science: An Introduction* by Mermin) and am happy with the result. The slides are available [here](https://speakerdeck.com/ahelwer/quantum-computing-for-computer-scientists).

Answer (score 0):

A really well-made resource explaining [Grovers algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm) is ['How the quantum search algorithm works'](https://quantum.country/search) on Quantum Country by Andy Matuschak and Michael Nielsen.

I think this fits your question nicely, as it is a fundamental algorithm, the explanation does not assume a lot of prior knowledge and the explanation focuses on a conceptual understanding.